# Is there a way to avoid typing QCoreApplication.translate("Context",?

Tags: python, translation, pyside2

To translate strings in PySide2 apps I need to call QCoreApplication.translate() and specify a context, which are a lot of characters to translate a short string.
ie: `QCoreApplication.translate("MyClassName", "Hello")`
I tried to do something like this:

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from functools import partial


class Translate:
    def __init__(self, context):
        self.context = context
        self.translate = partial(QCoreApplication.translate, self.context)

    def __call__(self, text):
        return self.translate(text)
```

This way `QCoreApplication.translate()` was called with the right context and in my sources I could have a shorter name, but the strings weren't picked up and stored in the *.ts files.
Is there a way to at least reduce the amount of boilerplate characters needed to translate Qt software written in python? Maybe by configuring pyside2-lupdate?

Comment: Your question is not clear, you could better explain what your problem is and what you want to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
The [issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-131) has been fixed in Qt 5.15.4+ and Qt 6+

---

First of all thanks to both **benjamin-forest** and **CryptoFool**, their answers were useful.

I found out that there are actually three distinct issues here:

- Custom functions are supported only by `pylupdate5` from PyQt5,
  while `pyside2-lupdate` has no configuration options, unlike `lupdate`
- Both `pylupdate5` and `pyside2-lupdate` have no way to guess the context when using global functions, therefore every string read by them would go to the `@default` context
- The default implementation of `self.tr()` gets its context at runtime, as stated in the official PyQt documentation

[Differences Between PyQt5 and Qt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/i18n.html#differences-between-pyqt5-and-qt)

> Qt implements internationalisation support through the `QTranslator`
> class, and the `translate()` and `tr()` methods. Usually `tr()` is used to
> obtain the correct translation of a message. The translation process
> uses a message context to allow the same message to be translated
> differently. In Qt `tr()` is actually generated by `moc` and uses the
> hardcoded class name as the context. On the other hand, translate
> allows the context to be specified explicitly.
>
> Unfortunately, because of the way Qt implements `tr()` it is not
> possible for PyQt5 to exactly reproduce its behaviour. The PyQt5
> implementation of `tr()` uses the class name of the instance as the
> context. The key difference, and the source of potential problems, is
> that **the context is determined dynamically in PyQt5**, but is hardcoded
> in Qt. **In other words, the context of a translation may change
> depending on an instance’s class hierarchy.**

My solution is to declare a private `__tr()` method to wrap `QCoreApplication.translate()`

```
def __tr(self, txt, disambiguation=None, n=-1):
    return QCoreApplication.translate("TestWidget", txt, disambiguation, n)
```

and configure pylupdate5 to look for it when called from setup.py:

```
if has_build_ui:
    class build_res(build_ui):
        """Build UI, resources and translations."""

        def run(self):
            # build translations
            check_call(["pylupdate5", "-tr-function", "__tr", "app.pro"])

            lrelease = os.environ.get("LRELEASE_BIN")
            if not lrelease:
                lrelease = "lrelease"

            check_call([lrelease, "app.pro"])

            # build UI & resources
            build_ui.run(self)
            # create __init__ file for compiled ui
            open("app/ui/__init__.py", "a").close()

    cmdclass["build_res"] = build_res
```

This way both `pylupdate5` gets the right context when generating the `.ts` files and `self.__tr()` has always the right context at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using classes, inheriting from QObject provides you a `self.tr("your text")` method, that will have proper context.

Replacing `QCoreApplication.translate()` by `QObject().tr("your string")` does works, but supposes you creates a new QObject each time you translate a string ...

It seems that doing some global `tr = QObject().tr` does work as well (I suspect this would rapidly becomes tricky).

Comment: My problem is that **pyside2-lupdate** wouldn't read any of the strings to be translated

Comment: Strange, I tested it and it seemed to work. May have been fooled one way or another, though.

Comment: I'll try again and let you know

Answer (score 1):

What comes right to my mind is this very simple function:

```
defaultContext = "MyClassName"

def translate(str, context=defaultContext):
    return QCoreApplication.translate(context, str)
```

You specify a default context when you define the function, and can also change it globally any time you want by just setting `defaultContext` to a different value. You can optionally pass in a different context with every call, but the call with the default is super simple and clean:

```
translated = translate("Hello")
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: My problem is that **pyside2-lupdate** wouldn't read any of the strings to be translated